# Java Enums Enforce Uniqueness For A Field

Tags: java, design-patterns, enums

I have an enum which in a simplified form looks like this.

```
public enum Codes{
    Code1("someCode1", "someState"),
    Code2("someCode2", "someState"),
    ...
    ...
    private final String m_code;
    private final String m_state;       
}
```

My objective is to enforce that when anyone else edits this enum to add a new value, say `Code100`, the `m_code` for `Code100` should not be the same as `m_code` for any of the previous `Code1`-`Code99`. The only way, I could think of was to write a unit test for this enum which would do that check. Is there a better solution to this problem?

Ideally, I would have liked a compile time error for this situation, but I am not sure this can be done in Java?

Comment: The solution by Peter is cleanest I think. Otherwise, I would just use the unit test. With a properly set up continuous integration, there should be no way for the code escaping into production untested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean you like to handle `m_code` as an unique-key?

Try

```
public enum Codes{
  someCode1("someState"),
  someCode2("someState"),
  ...
  ...
  private final String m_state;       
}
```

The name of the `enum` is always unique. Violations breaks earlier than Testing, earlier than running, earlier than compiling, violations breaks on syntax-check.

Comment: As an addition to this post he still can keep getCode() method and just return this.name();

Answer (score 1):

I would go with Peter’s answer if possible.  If you must name your enum values Code1 through Code99, you can enforce uniqueness as soon as the class is loaded:

```
public enum Codes {
    CODE1("someCode1", "someState"),
    CODE2("someCode2", "someState"),
    //...
    //...
    CODE99("someCode99", "someState");

    static {
        Set<String> codes = new HashSet<>();
        for (Codes value : values()) {
            if (!codes.add(value.code)) {
                throw new RuntimeException(
                    "Duplicate code string value: \"" + value.code + "\"");
            }
        }
    }

    private final String code;
    private final String state;
}
```

Comment: Perfect on conditions described above. cplusplusrat simplified alot and if my answer matches his problem its a fluke. Anyway, the class is loaded at load-time not at "runtime" maybe, maybe this is a cornercase we could maybe throw a full-gown Error (what a shock - who said that! ;D ).

Answer (score 0):

stick whatever needs to be unique in a static set and check that you added that in the constructors so it's all done at load time.